How to cluster features with matching property with SuperCluster (OpenLayers)
Is it possible to only cluster features with SuperCluster if those features have a matching property or attribute?
For example, I have points on one layer that belong to three different groups, and I want those groups to be clustered separately but on the same layer for performance purposes.
Someone figured out how to do it with OpenLayers' native Cluster (link), and an OpenLayers contributor said it could be done with the geometryFunction (SuperCluster's equivalent is geojsonFunction) - but how?
Basic example with SuperCluster on codesandbox.com
//fake data
const count = 2000;
const features = new Array(count);
const e = 20000000;
for (let i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
  const coordinates = [2 * e * Math.random() - e, 2 * e * Math.random() - e];
  features[i] = new Feature(new Point(coordinates));
  if (i % 2 == 0) {
    features[i].set('category', 'cat');
  } else {
    features[i].set('category', 'dog');
  }
}

const source = new VectorSource({
  features: features,
});

const styleCache = {};
function clusterStyle_fn(feature) {
  const size = feature.get('features').length;
  let style = styleCache[size];
  if (!style || size > 1) {
    style = styleCache[size] = new Style({
      image: new CircleStyle({
        radius: 10,
        stroke: new Stroke({
          color: '#000',
        }),
        fill: new Fill({
          color: '#FEE000',
        }),
      }),
      text: new Text({
        text: size.toString(),
        fill: new Fill({
          color: '#000',
        }),
      }),
    });
  } else {
    style = styleCache[size] = new Style({
      image: new CircleStyle({
        radius: 10,
        stroke: new Stroke({
          color: '#fff',
        }),
        fill: new Fill({
          color: '#FE6000',
        }),
      }),
      text: new Text({
        text: size.toString(),
        fill: new Fill({
          color: '#fff',
        }),
      }),
    });
  }
  return style;
}

const raster = new TileLayer({
  source: new OSM(),
});

const map = new Map({
  layers: [raster],
  target: 'map',
  view: new View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 2,
  }),
});

const clusterSource = new Supercluster({
  radius: 240,
  view: map.getView(),
  source: source,
  geojsonFunction: function (feature) {
    const geometry = feature.getGeometry();
    return {
      type: 'Feature',
      properties: feature.getProperties(),
      geometry: {
        type: 'Point',
        coordinates: toLonLat(geometry.getCoordinates()),
      },
    };
  },
});

const clusters = new AnimatedCluster({
  source: clusterSource,
  animationDuration: 700,
  style: clusterStyle_fn,
});

map.addLayer(clusters);


In the OpenLayers cluster source the geometry function is typically used to return a point geometry for other geometry types such as polygons but can also be used as a filter https://jsfiddle.net/bhxsqtza/

Thanks Mike - super helpful to know! I will play with my code and see if I can make it do exactly what I want with your suggestion (still wrapping my head around it!)

I ended up just using OpenLayers' native Cluster to group specific features into clusters via a newly created propertyFilter property, and referenced Mike's code to create a geometryFunction that shows/hides these features. However, I won't mark this as an answer as I wanted this to work with SuperCluster.
Here's the code I use to cluster features with a matching property:
this.propertyFilter = options.propertyFilter ? options.propertyFilter : null;

//Other stuff

cluster() {
      if (this.resolution === undefined || !this.source) {
        return;
      }
 
      const filterBy = this.propertyFilter;
      const extent = createEmpty();
      const mapDistance = this.distance * this.resolution;
      const features = this.source.getFeatures();
      const clustered: Record<string, true> = {};
    
      for (let i = 0, ii = features.length; i < ii; i++) {
        const feature = features[i];

        const featurePropertyId = feature.get(filterBy);

        if (!(getUid(feature) in clustered)) {
          const geometry = this.geometryFunction(feature);
          if (geometry) {
            const coordinates = geometry instanceof GeometryCollection ? geometry.getGeometries()[1].getCoordinates() : geometry.getCoordinates();
            createOrUpdateFromCoordinate(coordinates, extent);
            buffer(extent, mapDistance, extent);

            const neighbors = this.source
              .getFeaturesInExtent(extent)
              .filter(function (neighbor: Feature<Point>) {
                const uid = getUid(neighbor);
                const neighborPropertyId = neighbor.get(filterBy);
                if (uid in clustered) {
                  return false;
                }
                if (neighborPropertyId && featurePropertyId && neighborPropertyId !== featurePropertyId) {
                  return false;
                }
                clustered[uid] = true;
                return true;
              });
              
            this.features.push(this.createCluster(neighbors, extent));
        }
      }
    }
  }

